# How to say that the phone is held between shoulder and ear?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

What are common phrases an English native speaker would use for the pose of speaking on the phone where you use your shoulder to keep the receiver against your ear (and mouth), so your hands are free?

I have some ideas, but they all sound wooden, and I don't think I've ever heard anyone describe this pose in words. It's also pretty much impossible to google for a pose or look it up on leo.org or other dictionaries.

OK, since people keep asking for what phrasings I found, I'll provide two, though I was hoping I could avoid influencing people who answer here by not providing them: "balance on one's shoulder", "held/nestled/sandwiched between shoulder and ear".

Comment: The first thing that pops into my mind is "holding the phone with your shoulder." You should edit your question, and share a few of your ideas.

Comment: Welcome to English.SE. The [FAQ] and the linked document on how to ask a good question have more information about what should be included in your question.

Comment: J.R., I wanted to avoid 'poisoning' the results with my (probably wrong or clunky) ideas.

Comment: MetaEd, I read the FAQ and this question seemed on topic. Hence I posted. If you wanted to indicate I'm doing something wrong, I'd appreciate a more concrete criticism so I can fix it. Thanks!

Comment: -1 for another one of these "what is a phrase for [x y z]" questions that offers no explanation of what's wrong with just saying "[x y z]," or how we are to know that our answer won't be rejected for the same vague reason.

Comment: Evan, there is nothing wrong with the phrase. I just like some variety in my writing, and I'm not a native speaker, so wanted to find out what real people actually say. And I'm not rejecting anything, I even up-vote every answer that makes a sensible point (which so far are all of them).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Many people use the verb ***to cradle*** for this:

as in
[***cradling a phone on their shoulder***](https://www.google.com/search?q=phone+cradled+on+shoulder&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a#hl=en&safe=off&client=firefox-a&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3Aofficial&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=cradling+a+phone+on+their+shoulder&oq=cradling+a+phone+on+their+shoulder&gs_l=serp.3...14986.22828.1.22889.36.35.1.0.0.0.142.3661.12j22.34.0.efrsh..0.0...1.1.WN7U4AQ4QgU&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&fp=feba6114275f50ab&biw=1330&bih=725)

With variations of:
*phone cradled against her shoulder*
*cradled the phone to his shoulder*
*cradled between my ear and shoulder*
*cradled between neck and shoulder*
*cradled between his shoulder and ear*
*cradled between his shoulder and jaw*

Comment: The other answers are not bad, but this is definitely the one I encounter the most in actual use, by far.

Comment: This should be chosen as the answer.

Answer (score 6):

I thought it was "in the crook of the neck":

- http://www.theregister.co.uk/1999/08/17/mobile_phones_are_a_real/
- http://www.dailymail.co.uk/health/article-85401/What-day-office-does-body.html
- http://www.spine-health.com/conditions/neck-pain/neck-strain-causes-and-remedies
- https://www.prevent-rsi.com/rsi/names/carpal-tunnel-syndrome
- http://www.spine-health.com/video/video-what-causes-a-stiff-neck
- http://connection.ebscohost.com/c/articles/9710013763/yuppie-alert-mobile-phones-can-cause-pain-neck
- http://www.myphysio2go.com/2012/04/healthy-computer-habits/

Comment: If we combine your answer with the answer by @Jim , we'd get "cradling the phone in the crook of our neck", which is pretty much how Link #2 words it.  No matter how you say it, perhaps it's time to buy a [Rest-a-Phone](http://www.abcplas.com/pages/RAP_about.html) :^) (Note how the professionals at Super Rest-a-Phone call it _wedging_ the phone between the ear and shoulder).

Comment: @J.R.- Although I tend to think their word choice may be biased, after all they don't want to evoke nice images of babies peacefully sleeping in their cradles, they want to evoke uncomfortable images of things being wedged into place.

Comment: @Jim: that's a good point. I had only meant to illustrate that there's probably no single way to describe this position (I had no problem with the O.P.'s _nestled_ or _balanced_, either). But you're analysis is excellent – I hadn't thought about the marketing aspect of _wedge_ vs _cradle_.

Comment: Yeah, cradling or just holding I suppose.  Although I must admit with cradling I visualise holding something in the arms.

Answer (score 4):

> - With the phone propped on her shoulder...
> - With the phone pinned between her shoulder and her ear...
> - With the phone balanced on her shoulder...

Answer (score 2):

You'd have the [telephone **crooked** [under your chin]](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22crooked%20telephone%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&gs_nf=1&tok=b1txplnBdyfDzhuGbS78ZQ&ds=bo&pq=%22crooked%20telephone%22&cp=18&gs_id=z&xhr=t&q=%22telephone%20crooked%22&pf=p&tbo=1&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&oq=%22telephone%20crooked%22&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=70a4f081b0e8e93e&biw=1322&bih=886).

Answer (score 1):

A simpler way to say it would be: "She held/put/balanced the phone on her shoulder." In particular, you can get away with not mentioning the ear at all, since usage of the phone automatically implies ear proximity. If you are describing specifically the act of *switching* from holding the phone in one's hand to holding it on one's shoulder, you can say something like: "She transferred the phone to her shoulder to free up her hands."

Answer (score 0):

You might say *[scrunched](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/scrunch)*, as in “She scrunched the phone between her shoulder and ear and hurriedly scribbled notes.”